# I'm writing a links-checker in php and I can't get the HTTP error (e.g. 404 or 400) when the site displays a screen like 'this page can't be found'

Tags: php, regex, http-headers

I am making a links-checker tool to avoid broken links in our site content and it works when the page doesn't exist or can't be loaded - except when the external site replaces it with a screen saying something like 'This page doesn't seem to exist. Search for the content you are looking for from our menu...'.
Apart from the html/css/js code for this tool, here is the main PHP code that checks the links

```
$headers = get_headers($url);
$headers = (is_array($headers)) ? implode( "\n ", $headers) : $headers;
$exists = (bool)preg_match('#^HTTP/.*\s+[(200|301|302)]+\s#i', $headers);
$status = (is_array($headers)) ? $headers[0] : $headers;
```

Then js use this information including $status but it's not returning error code when the external site shows a 'not found' screen (e.g. `http://www.drdansiegel.com/resources/healthy_mind_platter`).

Answer (score 0):

You get back redirects before resolving to the 404. I would invert your logic, check to see if you have a `404` or `400` ever present.

```
$notexists = (bool)preg_match('#^HTTP/.*\s40[04]\s#mi', $headers);
```

Also, you should use the `m` modifier so the leading anchor matches each line, not the whole string.

Additionally, note a character class is a list of characters, you can't do groupings in it as you have. `[(200|301|302)]` says a `(`, `2`, `0`, `0` (again), `|`, `3`, `0` (again), etc. are all allowed. You would write that as `(200|301|302)` if you wanted `200`, `301`, or `302` to be allowed characters. You could use a character class for the last integer on the redirect status code (and should add `7` and `8` to that as though are valid redirects as well). So it could be `(200|30[1278])`.

Here's what your `$headers` contained from example link:

```
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
    [1] => Server: nginx
    [2] => Date: Sat, 15 May 2021 01:57:44 GMT
    [3] => Content-Type: text/html
    [4] => Content-Length: 162
    [5] => Connection: close
    [6] => Location: https://www.drdansiegel.com/resources/healthy_mind_platter
    [7] => HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
    [8] => Server: nginx
    [9] => Date: Sat, 15 May 2021 01:57:45 GMT
    [10] => Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    [11] => Content-Length: 0
    [12] => Connection: close
    [13] => Expires: Sat, 15 May 2021 02:57:45 GMT
    [14] => Cache-Control: max-age=3600
    [15] => X-Redirect-By: WordPress
    [16] => Location: https://drdansiegel.com/resources/healthy_mind_platter
    [17] => HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
    [18] => Server: nginx
    [19] => Date: Sat, 15 May 2021 01:57:46 GMT
    [20] => Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    [21] => Connection: close
    [22] => Vary: Accept-Encoding
    [23] => Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
    [24] => Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
    [25] => Link: <https://drdansiegel.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I couldn't get the HTTP error code with $notexists but I used your array of code to loop through it and it worked.